# What would happen to voltage if I connect an extremely long cable to one battery terminal?

Tags: voltage, power-engineering

Suppose I had a 9 volt battery and decided to connect an extremely long cable to one of the battery terminals as show in the picture below:

[image]

Assuming that we waited enough time for thing to settle down, the question is what would happen to the battery voltage if I was to meassure the voltage between point A and Point B? I am sure I am wrong but I believe the voltage would be close to zero.

The reason I say this is because the moment the cable is connected to the battery terminal, the electric potential along the whole cable length will need to become the same as the electric potential on the battery terminal. The problem is that the circuit is not closed so no more electrons will be allowed to flow from the positive to the negative terminal. This would mean that all the available electrons on the negative battery terminal will need to be distributed along the whole cable, which would mean very low density of electrons per the available area, which would mean very low electric field, which would mean very low voltage.

Do I make any sense?

Comment: It depends on the  input impedance of your measurement device and the actual impedance of that piece of cable you added.

Answer (score 2):

The potential is not about electrons, but about electric field. The field is propagating with speed of about the speed light. If you think with an analogy of a battery as a water pump and the voltage as a pressure, in your example it will be such a pump with a very long pipe connected to it. But the pressure at both of the ends of the pipe will be the same, and it won't require the water to travel from the pump to the other end.

Comment: Is an electrical field not formed between atoms with an excess of electrons and atoms with a lack electrons? If that is the case (and I thought that was the case), the electrical field should be directly proportional to the lack or excess of electrons between two points. Is that totally wrong?

Comment: The wire is not analogous to an empty pipe. It is "full" of electrons (water). The electrons near the battery are "pushed" with the electrons from the battery, these electrons are "pushing" the next ones and so on. So the "excess" of electrons from the battery is "propagated" to the very end of the wire. Of course, it is very simplified description, but it gives the intuitive idea.